# duvida com jsPdf - definição de colunas

Tags: javascript, html, json, jspdf, angular

tenho o seguinte json

```
{
"MedPaciente": [
    {
        "ProdutoModel": {
            "LaboratorioModel": {
                "id_laboratorio": 7951,
                "nome": "BOEHRINGER INGELHEIM",
                "data_cad": "28/12/2017",
                "situacao": 1
            },
            "id_produto": 232,
            "id_laboratorio": 7951,
            "codbarras": "7896026300704",
            "nome": "ANADOR 500MG 2COMP ",
            "situacao": 1,
            "alldata": "ANADOR 500MG 2COMP ",
            "data_cad": "17/01/2001"
        },
        "id_med_paciente": 44,
        "id_empresa": 1,
        "id_consulta": 59,
        "id_paciente": 4,
        "id_produto": 232,
        "qtde_embalagem": 20,
        "dose_diaria": 2,
        "lote": "1231",
        "vencto": null,
        "crm": "1325",
        "uf_crm": null,
        "medico": "aluisio da silva reis",
        "dt_lancto": "2018-02-06T00:00:00",
        "termino": "2018-02-26T00:00:00",
        "tipo": "medicamento",
        "qtde": 2
    }
```

}

o codigo a seguir define o nome da coluna e seu dataKey

```
 var columns = [
            { title: "Nome", dataKey: "MedPaciente.ProdutoModel.nome" },
            { title: "Laboratório", dataKey: "lab" },
            { title: "Qtde", dataKey: "qtde" },
            { title: "Ao Dia", dataKey: "dose_diaria" },
            { title: "Lote", dataKey: "lote" },
            { title: "Vecnto", dataKey: "vencto" },
            { title: "CRM", dataKey: "crm" },
            { title: "Médico", dataKey: "medico" }
        ];
```

a Primeira coluna é o nome do produto, no dataKey tentei "MedPaciente.ProdutoModel.nome" mas nao da certo, o pdf sai com o nome vazio.
ja as colunas qtde, Ao Dia, lote, etc, essas são preencidas normalmente (estão no novel zero do array).

como posso definir o nome do DataKey quando o elemento nao esta no nivel zero?

Answer (score 1):

Presumo que estas a falar do plugin AutoTable para o jsPDF.
Essa funcionalidade não é suportada pelo plugin AutoTable. Na documentação está descrito o formato json para colunas e dados e podes ver que não se consegue isso.
[plugin for jsPDF](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable)